# How to add an EventNotifier to Camel using Main class standalone

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to add an EventNotifier to my Apache Camel standalone application which uses the Main class from Camel.

http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

```
public void boot() throws Exception {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
    System.out.println("Starting Camel. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
    main.run();
}
```

I want to add an EventNotifier like in this cookbook example:

http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html

Here is my simple EventNotifier

```
@Override
public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {
    logger.info(event.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(EventObject event) {
    logger.info("Checked if enabled");
    return true;
}
```

Using Java DSL, I want to do something like:

```
context.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(new MyEventNotifier());
```

There are a few methods on Main that seems like they would be helpful: main.getOrCreateCamelContext() and main.getCamelContexts().

**getOrCreateCamelContext** will create a context but when main.run() is called, that context goes away (Camel-1 and is the only context but after main.run(), Camel-2 is the only context).

**getCamelContexts** is empty until main.run() is called.

I tried adding the EventNotifier in another thread after the context is created by Main but nothing shows in my log so I suspect the EventNotifier needs to be added before the context is started.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way: create an anonymous inner class and override the postProcessCamelContext method.

```
    Main main = new Main() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessCamelContext(CamelContext camelContext) throws Exception {
            super.postProcessCamelContext(camelContext);
            camelContext.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(new MyEventNotifier());
        }
    };
```