# How do I set PropertiesComponent when using Camel Main class?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using the Main class for a simple Java camel demo and need to set a PropertiesComponent for the Context, something like this:

```
    main.enableTrace();
    main.enableHangupSupport();
    main.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilderDemo());

    CamelContext context = main.getOrCreateCamelContext();
    PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
    pc.setLocation(“test.properties”);      
    context.addComponent("properties", pc);
```

When I run, I get:

No existing PropertiesComponent has been configured, creating a new default PropertiesComponent with name: properties

I can get this working without using the Camel Main helper?

Currently looking at this approach: [How to add an EventNotifier to Camel using Main class standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354698/how-to-add-an-eventnotifier-to-camel-using-main-class-standalone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how my project binds the PropertiesComponent for the MainSupport context:

```
    PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
    main.bind("properties", pc);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Thought I tried that but clearly not!